# Error when changing partition field in Iceberg, from spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-iceberg

we are writing to iceberg using spark, and when renaming the partition field name, we are getting a validation error:

```
org.apache.iceberg.exceptions.ValidationException: Cannot find source column for partition field: 1000: some_date: void(1)
```

It seems like Iceberg is referring to the existing table partition field name, which is irrelevant anymore - as there is a new partition field, and the write mode is "overwrite".

Any advice?
Here is a minimal reproducible example:

create the original table with partition field "some_date":

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType ,StructField, StringType
dataDF = [('1991-04-01',)]
schema = StructType([
        StructField('some_date',StringType(), True)])

spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local[1]').appName('example') \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame(data = dataDF, schema = schema)
spark.sql(f"use iprod")  # catalog
spark.sql(f"CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS iprod.test_schema")

df.write.mode("overwrite").format("parquet").partitionBy('some_date').saveAsTable("iprod.test_schema.example")
```

Try to overwrite the table with the same code, but the partition field renamed to some_date_2

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType ,StructField, StringType
dataDF = [('1991-04-01',)]
schema = StructType([
        StructField('some_date_2',StringType(), True)])

spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local[1]').appName('example') \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame(data = dataDF, schema = schema)
spark.sql(f"use iprod")  # catalog
spark.sql(f"CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS iprod.test_schema")

df.write.mode("overwrite").format("parquet").partitionBy('some_date_2').saveAsTable("iprod.test_schema.example")
```

Full trace:

```
: org.apache.iceberg.exceptions.ValidationException: Cannot find source column for partition field: 1000: some_date: void(1)
    at org.apache.iceberg.exceptions.ValidationException.check(ValidationException.java:46)
    at org.apache.iceberg.PartitionSpec.checkCompatibility(PartitionSpec.java:511)
    at org.apache.iceberg.PartitionSpec$Builder.build(PartitionSpec.java:503)
    at org.apache.iceberg.TableMetadata.reassignPartitionIds(TableMetadata.java:768)
    at org.apache.iceberg.TableMetadata.buildReplacement(TableMetadata.java:790)
    at org.apache.iceberg.BaseMetastoreCatalog$BaseMetastoreCatalogTableBuilder.newReplaceTableTransaction(BaseMetastoreCatalog.java:256)
    at org.apache.iceberg.BaseMetastoreCatalog$BaseMetastoreCatalogTableBuilder.createOrReplaceTransaction(BaseMetastoreCatalog.java:244)
    at org.apache.iceberg.CachingCatalog$CachingTableBuilder.createOrReplaceTransaction(CachingCatalog.java:244)
    at org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog.stageCreateOrReplace(SparkCatalog.java:190)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.AtomicReplaceTableAsSelectExec.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result$lzycompute(V2CommandExec.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result(V2CommandExec.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.doExecute(V2CommandExec.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.executeQuery$1(SQLExecution.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:686)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:619)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is because the Iceberg table format of your table is version 1.

You should update your table to version 2 (`format-version` table property).
AFAIK, it can be done via SQL:

```sql
ALTER TABLE catalog.ns.table
SET TBLPROPERTIES (
  'format-version' = '2'
)
```

But also in with the DataFrame API v2. Something like:

```py
df.writeTo('catalog.ns.table').using("iceberg").tableProperty("format-version", "2").createOrReplace()
```

You can read more about the Iceberg table format in the [spec](https://iceberg.apache.org/spec/#format-versioning) (while  [here](https://iceberg.apache.org/spec/#version-2) you'll find a summary of the changeset between version 1 and 2).

In case you wanna stick with version 1 you should `DROP` and then re-`ADD` the partition (via `ALTER TABLE`).